# Vulcanization is not working in polymer

Tags: polymer, lazy-loading, polymer-starter-kit, polymerfire, firebase-polymer

I have implemented lazy loading like this.After implemented this vulcanization is not working.

```
page('/home', function() {
     Polymer.Base.importHref('/components/home/home.html', function()
    {
     app.route = 'home';
    });
});
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make sure that your polymer.json file contains all file you want included in vulcanization.

Comment: polymer.json or bower.json?

Comment: polymer.json this file is used by the polymer build to know what files to include in your build